# shopify how to include querystring in application url

Tags: shopify

I am looking for a way to include a querystring for my shopify application preferences page so that i will be able to load the correct settings when a user is directed to the preferences page from shopify.

I am hoping to get the shop name from the querystring and store the settings according to that.

eg. mydomain/preferences/shopname

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You already get the shop name in the query string from Shopify in all cases unless you created the link into your App yourself, in which case you would be telling your own App about the current shop. So any clicks from preferences already tell you the shop.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Im not too sure I understand though. Currently within shopify when I edit my app settings I set the preference url to http://localhost/shopifyTesting/pref.aspx. I dont know how to include the shop name in this url so my app on can pick it up. Hope im making sense.

Comment: No one can get to your preferences URL unless they login. When they login you are forcing Shopify to provide the shopname... therefore you build a session, knowing the shop already.. hence you do not need it when accessing preferences.